# Access is not requested again after reinstalling the app in iOS12

Tags: ios, swift, privacy, ios12

After updating to iOS12 and testing the apps build in Xcode 9, we found out that after deleting and reinstalling the app - the user is not prompt again with a question regarding access to the Camera or Gallery.
On iOS11, every time the app is installed, iOS asks for permission.

I tested few random apps from AppStore to see how they behave and the conclution is - some of them do reset the access and some don't. So, I'm completely lost.

Also, as an info, but I'm not 100% sure about this: when there is a time period between deleting and installing the app (more than 1h), even on iOS 12 is asking for permission.

Is there any change there in iOS 12? Do you have any clue how to keep iOS 11 behaviour instead?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only certain way to test the authorization request process again after deleting your app is (and always has been) to go to the Settings app and choose General -> Reset -> Reset Location & Privacy. This is a major pain because you've now reset *all* your location and privacy settings.

My other suggestion (and it's only a suggestion) is that you try restarting the device after deletion of the app. Maybe, just maybe, this will cause the device to write something out to disk that will cause it to forget about its previous authorization of this app.